# Python 3.11 doesn't have pip installed and has no module _socket

Tags: python, pip

I had problems with my old python 3.10 (working with pycharm),
I installed the new 3.11 and the problems didn't go away.

I deleted all of the versions I had, including Pycharm, then I reinstalled my 3.11 and Pycharm and immediately encountered a problem where I couldn't reinstall packages using pip because pip wasn't recognized.

I tried opening older projects and when I tried to run them I got the line

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'
```

I deleted everything again and this time I deleted all the old projects and python related software and also removed it from path, then again I reinstalled python + Pycharm and still had no pip and the line: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'` appeared when I tried running some code.

---

I looked online on how to install pip and I got to this page:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/
I tried those methods to the best of my understanding but it didn't do anything, and also I am pretty sure I didn't fully understand what I needed to do.

Comment: Could you provide more information on your environment and how you installed python?

Comment: hi yes i think i can, i downloaded python straight from their website and installed it on my windows in the "regular" way, i ticked all the right boxes like "install pip" and "add python to path".
i did change the directory of the installation once because i wanted my pycharm and python.exe to be in the same place because it gave me some problems in the past.
about the environment, in not sure what it is, when i open a project in pycharm i choose Virtualenv.
in the past (before deleting python) i did use pipenv for the environment, but as i said, im not sure what it means and what it does.